# How can I retrieve and use the ID of a record I've created inside an RSpec/Capybara test?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, integration-testing, rspec2

I'm trying to visit a page for an object I'm creating inside an individual test.

```
it "should display some text" do
  log_employee_in
  create_ticket
  visit "/tickets/#{Ticket.last.id}"
  page.should have_content 'Some Text'
end
```

Inside the scope of this test, Ticket.last brings up the record ***prior*** to the one I've just created. After this individual test, I am able to retrieve the correct record in a rails test console by issuing `Ticket.last`.

It seems like the record isn't truly being persisted to the database until after the current test concludes.

How can I retrieve this ID inside the test?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the create_ticket helper?

Comment: I can, but I'm not sure how that will help. After the create_ticket method is called, a ticket exists for the test to utilize. But it's somehow not available/persisted to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the implementation of visit is not correct. If the other implementation of create_ticket is correct and you're sure about that. You can try this:

```
it "should display some text" do
  log_employee_in
  create_ticket
  visit ticket_path(Ticket.last.id) # you should be even able to get the ticket with Ticket.last
  page.should have_content 'Some Text'
end
```

Comment: As it turned out, I had a namespacing issue which I completely neglected. I should have been attempting to visit `"/service/tickets/#{Ticket.last.id}"`. However, my code would still have been ugly. Yours is definitely what I'm going to use. Thank you!